# Slide content on a page instead of loading each menu bar page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm new to web development. I'm making a site for a non-profit organization and I need some help. I am building a menu bar but instead of having to load each page separately, I am thinking of incorporating all the content on the same page. Only difference is that the new content will slide from the right whenever a new link is clicked.

Please check out www.pakgeosoc.org to see what i'm saying. I want to build a menu bar of this sort that will slide content from left or right whenever new link from menu bar is clicked.

I know this can easily be done using javascript. A simple explanation of how would be great! :)

P.S. The website I am building is a sister site of this website and my client (who owns this website) wants me to follow this template.

Comment: To post on StackOverflow you should really attempt writing something yourself and ask a specific question about how you're struggling. You'll probably want to do something along the lines of including the contents of the various pages in separate containers (e.g. divs) and use JavaScript (& probably Jquery) to slide the containers when it detects an onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check these questions asked before:

[JS or Css page slide transition between 2 full pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316402/js-or-css-page-slide-transition-between-2-full-pages)

[slide between pages using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518762/slide-between-pages-using-jquery)